# How the formula of a Arithmetic Progression works?

Tags: c

it is compiled in Turbo C3,

can someone explain how the SUM formula works?
because, I can't find anything in google that explains this formula

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<dos.h>
int main()
{
int ctr, limit, sum;
clrscr();
ctr=0;
printf("limit:");
scanf("%d",&limit);
for(ctr=1;ctr<=limit;++ctr)
{
delay(100);printf("%d",ctr);
printf("n");
}
sum=(limit*(2*1+(limit-1)*1))/ 2;
printf("The Sum of all # is:",sum);
getch();
}
```

sorry for my noob question

thanks in advance

Comment: The program has undefined behaviour because variable  limit was not initialized. There is no any sense to discuss this silly program.

Comment: `scanf("%d",&ctr);` --> `scanf("%d",&limit);`

Comment: I'm sorry, I typed that wrong,
I'm gonna edit it now

Comment: Where you initialize `sum`?

Comment: [This is the formula](https://upload.wikimedia.org/math/7/4/5/7456a8d727899b701af9e209bed95cdc.png)

Comment: how does that formula works?, can somebody explain or link something that discusses that the easiest way, sorry I'm noob.

Comment: @Jonathan Tapnio This n * ( n + 1 ) / 2 is well-known formula to calculate the sum of the series 1, 2, 3, ..., n

Comment: Here's a link on [Arithmetic Progression](http://www.math10.com/en/algebra/arithmetic-progression.html).

Comment: I gets more interesting when you sum squares, and then consider also the formula for sum of cubes, and so on.

Comment: I *like* the `* 1`... Wonder if some `+ 0` are missing...

Comment: 1) Indent your code. 2) Don't use Turbo C anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
sum=(limit*(2*1+(limit-1)*1))/ 2;
```

actually is the same as this formula:

[image]

where `Sn` denotes the sum of `n` terms, `n` is the number of terms(`limit`) and `a1` is the first term of the AP and `d` is the common difference. All this information is found in the [Wikipedia page for arithmetic progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum).

Answer (score 1):

One way to explain this.

Write all the the numbers twice, once forward once backwards, then add these two series:

```
    1 +   2 +   3 + ... + n-2 + n-1  +  n    
    n + n-1 + n-2 + ... +   3 +   2  +  1
-----------------------------------------
  n+1 + n+1 + n+1 + ... + n+1 + n+1 + n+1
```

So there are n x (n+1)'s and since you added two copies, divide this by 2, so the formula is

```
sum = (n * (n+1)) / 2
```